# How can I join two videos at equal frames?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I need to join multiple videos together, with the next one starting somewhere in the middle of the previous one. Therefore, I cant just put them one after the other, instead I need to find out where the next on starts.

To be more precisely, I have multiple parts of one video, unevenly splitted, which I would like to join into one. However, each one repeats the last few minutes of the previous one. For example, if the original is 30 minutes long, the first part may run from 00:00:00 till 00:07:00, while the second one runs from 00:05:37 till 00:14:56 and the third one runs from 00:12:53 till 00:18:21, and so forth. They follow no pattern whatsoever, but they have the same resolution, codec, framerate, etc.

What I would like to do is to concatenate them so that they are one again. Best would be a program which can do that on its own, but one that does tell me at which point of the first part [the second part] the second part [the third part] starts would be enough, from that point I could do the joining on my own (using ffmpeg).

What I already thought of is using ffmpeg to output every video frame into an image. I would then write a small program which would hash each image and output if one of part 1 and one of part 2 would be equal, so I could join them at this point using ffmpeg. However, that would be very slow and very tedious and create a huge amount of files and data. I would like to use it only as a "last resort".

Does such a program or script or something that would help me in any way exist for windows ? And if not, is there a better way (in terms of speed and required input, or, preferable, both) than what I proposed ? I do not need a perfect connection, but it should still feel like it was one video in the first place (no second long skip or pause or big artifacts).

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: Your hashing idea wouldn't work either; video compression is lossy so you don't get exactly the same frame back as you put in. Then each frame uses the frames that came before it to improve the compression so you'll get small differences that will prevent the hash matching.  I think you're gonna have ta do it by hand ... sorry.

Comment: I think you're right, haven't thought about that.. So yes, thank you, gonna do it by hand now.